# Starting Point for Creating Marketplace

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to create an online marketplace with a fairly limited featureset. Users should be able to register and list items for sale. All items will be of the same type but with different attributes, such as "release date", "quality" and "price". Users will be able to set that information on the listings and input their paypal information in order to receive direct payment from customers.

If it helps, the idea is kind of like a scaled down etsy meets ebay (but with buy it now only arrangements).

I have no real php/mysql experience, however I'd like to learn with this project. Can anyone point me in the direction of some good tutorials or concepts needed? I do have some general coding and lots of html/css/javascript experience.

Comment: don't use any project that evolves real money to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for that you need good php and mysql and also the database knowledge the html is the must and css is very important for the great user interface

here you will get general information and tutorial [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info),[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info)